# Installing Moodle on windows - Problem with intl plugin

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle on Windows 10, using the package I downloaded from here  [Moodle Windows Installation](https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Wkindows_installation).

I downloaded it, uncompress it, and run "Start Moodle". Then I open "http://localhost" and moodle installation starts. I'm stuck on this screen:

[image]

It orders me to install intl plugin on php. I went to php.ini, on the path I've downloaded the package, and the line `extension=php_intl.dll` is already there. the lines :

```
[intl]
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

I had to add/uncomment. But even restarting the machine, when i return to the installation, the same error persists. The php_intl.dll file is on the ext folder.